# Reflection on a doctrine2 proxy object

Tags: php, reflection, symfony, doctrine-orm

As far as I can see, reflection methods like `property_exists()` won't work on doctrine2 proxy objects.

In this case, the proxy is retrieved thru a relationship `$user->getCity()`

How can I check if a property exists / is set in this case?

Comment: A doctrine2 proxy class is just like any other class. It should work if the method is there. And as far as I know doctrine generates those wrapper methods. What's the exact usage? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 9):

The solution is `ReflectionClass::getParentClass()`.

So a code like this should work:

```
$reflect = new \ReflectionClass($proxyObject);

if ($proxyObject instanceof \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Proxy)
    // This gets the real object, the one that the Proxy extends
    $reflect = $reflect->getParentClass();

$privateProperty = $reflect->getProperty('privateProperty');
$privateProperty->setAccessible(true);
$privateProperty->setValue($proxyObject, $yourNewValue);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks @aerendir

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check if the proxy is initialized first:

```
if (
    $entity instanceof \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Proxy
    && ! $entity->__isInitialized()
) {
    $proxy->__load();
}
```

This basically enforces loading of the proxy: after that, everything will just work as if you had an instance of the original entity.

Public properties are not currently supported by the ORM by the way, though the feature will be implemented in Doctrine ORM 2.4. That way, you will just be able to access public properties without worrying about the object being or not a proxy.

Comment: Yes, the proxy is initialized.. So what you're saying is that I can't use reflection methods like `property_exists()`atm?

Comment: You can, but only if the proxy is initialized: otherwise the "fake" data structure it represents will be empty.

Comment: That's weird because I'm sure the proxy is initialized. Btw `property_exists()`evaluates to `false`. However, in case I do $user->city, I get an `can't access private property..` error. Weird!

Comment: @ThomasK that seems to be quite normal if you didn't define a magic getter/setter.

Comment: Ok.. so the answer to the question should be something like: Reflection methods won't work with proxy objects unless you define a magic getter/setter. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You're misunderstanding. This is basic PHP OOP: https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/4960682

An overview on your base class would be useful.

Comment: Note: this will likely work without any hacks in 3.x: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/1241

Comment: @Ocramius didn't work if i want to Reflect the class and get the list of properties

Comment: "didn't work" is not how you report an issue (in any software development methodology). Please clarify: this is how the ORM does it internally as well btw.

Comment: I have the same exact problem: also calling `$entity->__load()`, `$reflected->getProperty('propertyName');` tells that the property doesn't exist. And also dumping the `ReflectionClass`, the property seems not exists: only `__initializer__`, `__cloner__`, `__isInitialized__` and `lazyPropertiesDefaults` exists. But these are of the `Proxy` object and not of the original object.